# Storing AWS access/secret keys, or role policies; which should be stored in vault?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, vault

So I'm running into a strange architectural issue involving vault, and I'm throwing it out to the web because I don't think how we're proposing to do it is correct

Currently we have quite a few users for gitlab pipelines, where we save their access/secret keys in env variables for use by our pipelines. WE in turn cycle the access/secrets of every user every 90 days, with the values stored in keeper for use if needed. as you can guess, it's tedious.

So I was conversing with the person that's been put in charge of being our vault admin, on how we can have it where vault can store the access/secret keys for each of our pipeline users when they're updated every ninety days, presumably through a lambda function or pipeline. Instead there's already a plan in place where each role will have their policies stored in vault (even though there's a character limit that we do hit with some of our policies), and then the pipelines will call the roles that way instead. I'm not really understanding why we're doing it that way instead of just doing a k/v access/secret storage setup, as it feels like we're duplicating data in both vault and aws. trying to have it explained was like trying to watch a tv program in another language.  I'm wondering if anyone else here could possibly shed some light as to why they'd want to do it that way, and why it would be better?

Comment: their policies stored in vault? or the role name? you need the role name to assume it, not the entire policy?? the pipeline doesn't 'call' the role policy

Comment: It would be the policy data stored in vault, using the role name to call it. That's how it's being planned anyways. TO me it sounded strange as we already have the policy data for roles in aws iam so it's a duplication of data in two different spots.

Comment: I'm assuming they are storing an inline session policy to tailor the permissions for each pipelines even further than the main role that's being assumed. the reason why assuming roles is better is that they will max live up to 72 hours while access/secret k/v are long-lived. in a case where they are compromised, there's a huge benefit here for assuming a role using STS to get temporary credentials needed to run the pipeline job. does that help?

Comment: you are canadiancreed as an individual, a family member at home, patient at the dentist, an employee at your work of place etc. What you're allowed to do here is not determined by who you are as an individual but by the role you are playing in that situation. Using k/v means you have all the powers that canadiancreed would have *all the time* & if someone else got your ID, they could also be the same until you figure that out someday. Using temp creds however you have to confirm you are canadiancreed at least every 72 hours so someone can only be you as much as 72 hrs.

Comment: the policy being stored in vault is an inline policy which even further limits the 'patient' role (assumed role) you have at the dentist (pipeline) by stating that for this appointment (temp session for this pipeline job), you're not allowed to talk at all (limit the job to only access EC2). multiple people can be a patient but depending on their medical history, each have unique constraints. sorry for wall of text, but does all of this make it a bit clearer?

Comment: A bit? I guess what I'm wondering is why a time limit couldn't be enforced on the user, along with applying restrictive policies within AWS IAM instead of storing the policy json in vault.

Comment: A user's access keys have no time limit and are long-lived; that is the entire point of assuming a role from outside of AWS. You can also apply restrictive policies within IAM for the assumed role however I assume they want to limit each pipeline job even more for tighter security. Security in general is a lot of 'can do' but the answer to 'should do' depends on the situation itself.